# Why doesn't this code work? i am just trying to slice.(in python)

Tags: python, slice

When I enter this code, there is an error in the way a slice works...It won't let me enter it, and it overall just wont work.

```
verb_1 = raw_input("Enter a word")
verb_2 = verb_1.lower()
verb_2_ending = verb_2[-2:]
if verb_2_ending == "ar": 
    ar_verb = raw_input("you've chosen an AR verb. What tense would you like")
elif verb_2_ending == "er":
    er_verb = raw_input("you've chosen an ER verb. What tense would you like")
else :
    ir_verb = raw_input("you've chosen an IR verb. What tense would you like")

if ar_verb == "subjunctive":
    subject_1 = raw_input("What is the subject")
elif  ar_verb == "present":
    subject_2 = raw_input("What is the subject")
else :
    subject_3 = raw_input("What is the subject")
```

Yields the error:

```
Enter a word : hablar 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module> 
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means.  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is it?  What does the program not do that you want it to do?

Comment: What does this have to do with subtraction?

Comment: Enter a word :                                                       
 hablar                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'                  this is what it says when i hit enter

Comment: You haven't defined what your actual problem is, but if you choose an ER verb then you never actually set the ar_verb variable which is what you're checking for in your second block of conditional statements. The code is very incomplete, you should finish the code and then post any questions.

Comment: @user2387706 -- that error doesn't occur with the code you pasted above (There is only one "`-`" and it isn't doing subtraction).  I think you have some other errors (potential `NameError` with `ar_verb` for instance) -- But that will not lead to the type error you described.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're looking for is called slicing not subtraction and specifically in line 3. 
 
It's working okay when I run the code you've pasted here in idle and this is because the else statements should take care of any type errors from user input.
 You can however read more on strings and how slicing. Try this: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html

Comment: Depending on which Python one is using, there are some variations in string behavior. The lastest tutorial for Python3 http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings, and the latest Python 2 tutorial is http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings